# selinux and ntp , dose selinux heve negative impact on ntp

Tags: linux, redhat, ntp, selinux

we have redhat linux servers

in spite chrony.conf is set correctly with the right ntp servers

we see very strange behavior that time is still sync to ntp server but change from some reason

we suspect that selinux cause this but we cant be sure ( selinux is enabled for now)

is it possible that selinux give negative impact on NTP ?

reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469822/how-to-troubleshoot-selinux-issues

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're not mentioning the Linux distribution and version you're using. Based on the tag "redhat" and "chrony" you're likely using RHEL/CentOS 7 or 8.

The default SELinux configuration in RHEL/CentOS 7 or 8 is suited for chrony and no manual configuration is necessary. If you're experiencing NTP synchronisation errors, the issue is most likely not SELinux related (usually it's a firewall or network issue, broken NAT/masquerading in proprietary firewall applicances or strange routers).

If you still believe that SELinux could have impact, follow the steps from the reference you posted and provide the AVC denied errors here. Until there are no denials, SELinux is not the cause.